Dev containers and Sharepoint framework - Is it even possible to use dev containers in local machine to create webparts?
Sharepoint framework requires a bunch of stuff to be installed in the developer's local machine. I wonder if it's possible to use a correctly configured devcontainer.json and use it in VSCode.
I tried to install everything manually. So I installed the selected node version, Yeoman sharepoint generator, typescript, and gulp-cli. Everything compiles ok but when I try to do the gulp serve the page complains about not having access to the manifest. See the picture
When the alert is dismissed, the app does not load.
The app runs perfectly in the local machine with no container
